# How to execute an Oracle stored procedure via a database link

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, database-link

Can I call a stored procedure in Oracle via a database link?

The database link is functional so that syntax such as...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable@myRemoteDB
```

is functioning.  But is there a syntax for...

```
EXECUTE mySchema.myPackage.myProcedure('someParameter')@myRemoteDB
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The syntax is

```
EXEC mySchema.myPackage.myProcedure@myRemoteDB( 'someParameter' );
```

Comment: @xtsoler - That would work for a stored function, not a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you know how can i invoke a stored procedure with parameters?

Comment: @Afaria - The example I posted is passing a parameter (the string 'someParameter').

Answer (score 1):

check http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.database.ado/2005-08/msg00056.html

one needs to use something like

```
cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN foo@v; END;"
```

worked for me in vb.net, c#

Answer (score 0):

for me, this worked

```
exec utl_mail.send@myotherdb(
  sender => 'myfromemail@giggle.com',recipients => 'mytoemail@giggle.com, 
  cc => null, subject => 'my subject', message => 'my message'
);
```