# Call SQL Server functions via Oracle database link

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-link

Is there a way to execute the following statement from Oracle using a database link to a SQL Server instance without having to create a view on the target instance?

```
select db_name(), @@SERVERNAME
```

I have tried

```
"select db_name(), @@SERVERNAME"@DbLink
```

but that did not succeed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run SQL Server Stored Procedure via Database Link from Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534176/run-sql-server-stored-procedure-via-database-link-from-oracle)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
select dbo.FunctionName@dblink('value') from dual;
```

But you need to tell the dblink which functions must be available through the dblink. See the manual at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11050/admin.htm#i1007467

Comment: Thanks. As I no longer work in a company that uses Oracle I cannot test it. Have upvoted your answer though.