# how to execute sql Procedure to get result in Oracle View without conn configuration

Tags: sql-server, oracle

EXEC [dbo].[sql_store_proc_name] @MSSQL08 in oracle 
gives error
PLS-00201: identifier '[dbo].[sql_store_proc_name] @MSSQL08' must be declared

Comment: How does this relate to SQL Server and Oracle DB? The two are different products with incompatible SQL dialects.

Comment: I have a store procedure in SQL. and i need to call it using Oracle db to get result in oracle view.

Comment: but i cant configure it using http://www.easysoft.com/applications/oracle/database-gateway-dg4odbc.html like this

Comment: i used this method too, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14584791