# Dynamic Procedure Execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, remote-access

Hi I have to execute a remote call ...

```
DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO@DB_LINK()
```

... from a stored procedure.

As the value of DB_LINK is to be obtained during runtime. It should be executed dynamically. I tried to use

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO@'||DB_LINK||'()';
```

But I get the following error

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Can anyone advise me on how to execute the Stored Procedure dynamically?

Comment: Can you try: 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO@'||DB_LINK

Comment: well i am not sure if it will work but try do it like this '||DB_LINK()

Comment: Still not working. I receive the same error.

Comment: using '||DB_LINK(). It takes DB_LINK() as a function. And throws DB_LINK() function not found.

Comment: Your syntax seems to be correct: http://stackoverflow.com/q/240788/272735 Are you sure the value of `DB_LINK` is correct and the database link has privileges to execute `DBMS_STATS` package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue lies in the precise wording of the error message: `invalid SQL statement`.  As [the PL/SQL manual says](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#BHCEBBAI), EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is for executing dynamic SQL statements.

You are executing a procedure call i.e. PL/SQL not SQL.  So you need to pass an anonymous block to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'begin  DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO@'||DB_LINK||'() ;  end;' 
    ;
```

---

DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO takes no parameters, so the empty brackets are optional.  By all means include them if they make you feel happier.

Answer (score -1):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO@'||DB_LINK();
```

should work if DB_LINK is a global function returning a VARCHAR2 string.

Comment: DB_LINK appears to be a variable.  The `()` belong to the call to FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO .